# VSTS with gulp v.4.0.0

Tags: node.js, gulp, azure-devops

I'm having the gulp version of one of my projects. Previously we were using version 3.9.1 and we were hestitative updating.

After updating i have fixed all local issues and tested the project on a different computer (after updating the installed gulp there as well) it works fine.

Our automatic deployment however won't agree with me.

After a check-in our VSTS does the following steps

1. install npm
2. execute command
3. build project

However, this produces the following error.

```
Working directory changed to D:\a\1\s\MVC
Using gulpfile D:\a\1\s\MVC\gulpfile.js
C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129
gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
     ^
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

This error seems to be caused by an out of date cli version of gulp. But i can't figure out how to update this using VSTS.

**Concrete problem**

How do i update gulp cli in VSTS

***What have i done already?***

After some checking i saw the npm version installed was very old (3.10.8). I've dragged in a nodejs installer which updates to the latest version and gives me the latest version of nodejs, and a much newer version of npm (5.6.0) which i've used at on-hands computers to update the cli version. however i can't figure out how to do this in VSTS.

Comment: What version of gulp is your package.json asking for? I think thats your issue

Comment: package.json is asking for "^4.0.0"

Comment: If you use package.json scripts you can call to the local gulp or call it directly with ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp gulpfile.js, that way you dont use the system CLI and can define the exact version as you already have as ^4.0.0

Comment: Again the same problem :( I can get this working locally, but i don't know what command to use to get this working in VSTS. I'm taking a look at it today and will let you know if i've figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install/update gulp-cli through NPM task:

[image]

BTW, the package in package.json will be installed on current project/folder instead of global, you need to call gulp command through npm command (scripts property of package.json) to use package in current project/folder or specify the path directly (e.g. ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp)

Comment: Apologies for my late response, got sick and was out of the running for a few days.
This suggestion helped fixing my problems.
Key in this suggestion was the fact i should do it in the root folder of the source control instead of inside the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using `Hosted Agent` which the installed npm version is 3.10.8. You just need to add a Node Tool Installer task in your build definition and set it to use "8.x" version. It will install the 8.x version which include npm 5.6.0.
[image]

npm version before Node Tool Installer task:
[image]
npm version after Node Tool Installer task:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found worked for me was to change the Pipeline from `Hosted` to `Hosted VS2017`.

I had completed a PR that upgraded the Gulp to 4.0, and the PR build completed but the CI build failed with strange results. After a lot of searching, I narrowed it down to the PR build already being set to `Hosted VS2017` (it was building C# projects too that required them) and the CI build was only doing the Gulp build and was set to `Hosted`.

[image]